# Kotlin version issue

Tags: android, kotlin

(Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.2.71) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.3.0))

How can I solve this?

Comment: `How can I solve this?` ... **WHAT**?!

Comment: you can solve it by changing 1.2.71 to 1.3.0

Answer (score 2):

In `build.gradle`, look for `kotlin_version` or `kotlinVersion`, and change it from `1.2.71` to `1.3.0` (Note: the version variable could also possibly be defined in another `.gradle` script in the project, or in `gradle.properties`, instead of `build.gradle`).